# Sinch Calling not working for another country

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

After setting up Sinch voice and video call on my app and testing it, it worked good for India users. But when my Dubai users are using, getting error: Error(code: 1002, domain: network, error type: Network, message: DeafultHttpService: SSL handshake aborted). I'm assuming this is  Sinch's side issue, as the calling is working fine in india.
Using sinch-android-rtc-3.12.4 library for implementation.

Can anyone help if this an error on my side?

I have searched online but cannot find any information regarding it.

Comment: Welcome Sohil, which library you are using to make api call

Comment: @Priyankagb hello thank you for response, i am using sinch-android-rtc-3.12.4 library.

Comment: may b related to this issue https://github.com/sinch/app-app-calling-android/issues/31

Comment: Dubai dont like Voip apps, so its likely its blocked by Dubai.

Comment: yes this is the issue @cjensen thank you so much

Comment: anyone have idea about this issue ? i used sinch-android-rtc-4.8.6+b14862c.aar. call time return this message. ...... error=SinchError[errorType=GENERIC, code=403, message='Unable to connect call (403)'